# preserving the state of check boxex in customtreectrl

Tags: wxpython

I am using customtreectrl in wxpython with checkboxes. Once I submit I would like to save the state of the checkboxes in the customtreectrl. How can I save the checked state of a customtreectrl with checkboxes.Please help me.
Sushma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and use the "persist" library in the AGW package. This will allow you to save the state of  (almost) any wxPython widget across sessions. See the PersistentControls demo in the AGW library.